# Stacknavigator issue in react-native(how to pass props in routes)

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

app.js : It contains routes to all the screens. Is it neceessary to pass props in route? For example, When i display blog details (this.props.navigation.navigate('BlogDetailsRT',{id:blog_id}) i pass id of the blog. Do i need to specify it in the route also?? If it is then how to do that??

```
 const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
   CreateBlogRT: {
  screen: CreateBlog
  },
  BlogDetailsRT: {
  screen: BlogDetails
 },
EditBlogRT: {
  screen: EditBlog
},
DeleteBlogRT: {
  screen: DeleteBlog
},
HomeRT: {
  screen: Home
 },
 },
{
initialRouteName: 'HomeRT'
```

}
   );

```
  const MyRoutes = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
       export default class App extends React.Component {

       render() {
  return (
    <MyRoutes />

  );
}
}
```

Home.js: Onclicking the BlogDetails, now app crashes.

```
 <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('BlogDetailsRT', { id: blogid })} underlayColor='#31e981'>
                        <Text style={styles.buttons}> Blog details</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
```

Please someone help me.How to pass props in routes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to compulsorily pass props in navigation. It is only passed when you need to use it in next screen

Can you tell me when app crashes, what error does it displays? You can even try passing static value in "id" if it works then try passing dynamic value